# need to add a house ID to a member

Tags: php, mysql

I will start by telling you what I want my code to do and how it does it.

A member creates an account and then creates a house, therefore becoming the house admin. The admin then must be able to invite other users to join the house through email. When the user is sent the email I would like the email to have the house_id attached so that when the member who received the email is filling in the registration form, the program already knows what house the member is a part of and can save it as so in the database. I hope I am making sense.

So far all I can get working if when the admin creates the house, their member_id is assigned to the house. So you can tell who the admin of the house is. I cannot get the house_id to add to the member's table, so that in the member table i can see what member is a part of what house.

I have a member class, a member DAO, a house class and a houseDAO.

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this as I am very stumped.

Sorry if i have no explained clearly enough as I am very new to this language. 
Thanks in advance.

**Member Class**

```
<?php
class Member {
    private $id;
    private $first_name;
    private $last_name;
    private $email;
    private $birthday;
    private $password;
    private $house_id;


    public function __construct($i, $fName, $lName, $eml, $birth, $pwd, $house_id) {
        $this->id = $i;
        $this->first_name = $fName;
        $this->last_name = $lName;
        $this->email = $eml;
        $this->birthday = $birth;
        $this->password = $pwd;
        $this->house_id = $house_id;
    }
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function getFN() { return $this->first_name; }
    public function getLN() { return $this->last_name; }
    public function getEmail() { return $this->email; }
    public function getBirthday() { return $this->birthday; }
    public function getPassword() { return $this->password; }
    public function getHouseID() { return $this->house_id; }


    public function setId($i) { $this->id = $i; }
    public function setFN($fn) { $this->first_name = $fn; }
    public function setLN($ln) { $this->last_name = $ln; }
    public function setEmail($n) { $this->email = $n; }
    public function setBirthday($b) { $this->birthday = $b; }
    public function setPassword($p) { $this->password = $p; }
    public function setHouseID($h) { $this->house_id = $h; }


}
?>
```

**MemberDAO**

```
<?php
require_once 'DAO.php';

class MemberDAO extends DAO {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insert($member) {
        if (!isset($member)) {
            throw new Exception("Member required");
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Member(first_name, last_name, email, birthday, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $params = array($member->getFN(), $member->getLN(), $member->getEmail(), $member->getBirthday(), $member->getPassword());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not save member: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve new member's id: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $id = $row[0];
        $member->setId($id);
    }

    public function delete($member) {
        if (!isset($member)) {
            throw new Exception("Member required");
        }
        $id = $member->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("Member id required");
        }
        $sql = "DELETE FROM Member WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($member->getId());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not delete member: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function update($member) {
        if (!isset($member)) {
            throw new Exception("Member required");
        }
        $id = $member->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("Member id required");
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE Member SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, email = ?, birthday = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($member->getFN(), $member->getLN(), $member->getEmail(), $member->getBirthday(), $member->getPassword(), $member->getId());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not update member: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function getMember($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($id);
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve member: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $member= null;
        if ($stmt->rowCount == 1) {
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $id = $row['id'];
            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $birthday = $row['birthday'];
            $pwd = $row['password'];
            $member = new Member($id, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $birthday, $pwd);
        }
        return $member;
    }

    public function getMembers() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Member";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve members: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $members = array();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        while ($row != null) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            $birthday = $row['birthday'];
            $pwd = $row['password'];

            $member = new Member($id, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $birthday, $pwd);
            $members[$id] = $member;

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        return $members;
    }
}
?>
```

**House Class**

```
<?php
class House {
    private $id;
    private $house_name;
    private $no_members;
    private $member_id;


    public function __construct($i, $house_name, $no_members, $m_id) {
        $this->id = $i;
        $this->house_name = $house_name;
        $this->no_members = $no_members;
        $this->member_id = $m_id;

    }
    public function getId() { return $this->id; }
    public function getHouseName() { return $this->house_name; }
    public function getNoMem() { return $this->no_members; }
    public function getMember_id() { return $this->member_id; }


    public function setId($i) { $this->id = $i; }
    public function setHouseName($hn) { $this->HouseName = $hn; }
    public function setNoMem($nm) { $this->no_members = $nm; }
    public function setMember_id($mID) { $this->member_id = $mID; }


}
?>
```

**HouseDAO**

```
<?php
require_once 'DAO.php';

class HouseDAO extends DAO {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insert($house) {
        if (!isset($house)) {
            throw new Exception("House required");
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO House(house_name, no_members, member_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $params = array($house->getHouseName(), $house->getNoMem(), $house->getMember_id());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not save House: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve new House's id: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $id = $row[0];
        $house->setId($id);
    }

    public function delete($house) {
        if (!isset($house)) {
            throw new Exception("House required");
        }
        $id = $house->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("House id required");
        }
        $sql = "DELETE FROM House WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($house->getId());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not delete House: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function update($house) {
        if (!isset($house)) {
            throw new Exception("House required");
        }
        $id = $house->getId();
        if ($id == null) {
            throw new Exception("House id required");
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE House SET house_name = ?, no_members = ?, member_id = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($house->getHouseName(), $house->getNoMem(), $house->getMember_id());
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not update House: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }
    }

    public function getHouse($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM House WHERE id = ?";
        $params = array($id);
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute($params);
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve House: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $house = null;
        if ($stmt->rowCount == 1) {
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $id = $row['id'];
            $member_id = $row['member_id'];
            $house_name = $row['house_name'];
            $no_members = $row['no_members'];

            $house = new HouseDAO($id, $house_name, $no_members, $member_id);
        }
        return $house;
    }

    public function getHouses() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM  House";
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        $status = $stmt->execute();
        if ($status != true) {
            $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
            throw new Exception("Could not retrieve houses: " . $errorInfo[2]);
        }

        $houses = array();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        while ($row != null) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $house_name = $row['house_name'];
            $no_members = $row['no_members'];
            $member_id = $row['member_id'];



            $house = new House($i, $house_name, $member_id, $m_id);
            $houses[$id] = $house;

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
        }
        return $houses;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry, but this is waaaay to much code to just be able to help you

Comment: Your data structure implies that a member can be in one (and only one) house.  You may have more flexibility to use a `house_members` link table that relates these two separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the right track. I think you need to call this function on the Member Class:

```
public function setHouseID($h) { $this->house_id = $h; }
```

from within the House Class constructor. And as mentioned, unless you want only one member per house, you're going to need a separate child table to store houseid / memberid pairings.

Comment: a member can only be a part of one house, thats the intended structure.

i was trying to call that, but when creating a house the ID is only being created then and I need that ID to add to the member table at the same time, if you know what i mean?

Comment: @Topener could you please point me in the right direction? I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You have to 1st insert into the House, to get the id, and then insert into member.